# How to prevent onclick event with another one JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a div which acts as drag and drop. It has also select file functionality.
When file is selected, I want a customer to be able to delete it and select another one. 
So I am changing the content of a div with input onchange.
Problem occures wneh I want to delete a file, filebrowser opens automaticaly, and I want to prevent it.
Here is my code:

HTML

```
 <div id="drop-zone"
      ondrop="drag_drop(event)" 
      ondragover="return false"
      onclick="selectFile()"
 >
   <span class="drop-zone__title">Drop your file here</span>
   <span class="drop-zone__subtitle">or select a file</span>
 </div>
 <input type="file"
        name="upload-file"
        id="upload-file"
        accept=".pdf,.docx"
        aria-invalid="false"
        onchange="changeFile()"
 />
```

JS:

```
 const dropZone = document.querySelector('#drop-zone')
 const uploadFile = document.querySelector('#upload-file')

function drag_drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  if (event.dataTransfer.files[0]) {
    uploadFile.files = event.dataTransfer.files
    dropZone.innerHTML = '<div>' + event.dataTransfer.files[0].name + 
                         '<button class="removeFile" onclick="fileRemove(event)">
                          <i class="far fa-times"></i>
                          </button> 
                          </div>'
  dropZone.classList.add('drop-success');
}

function selectFile() {
 if (uploadFile.files.length == 0) uploadFile.click()
}

function changeFile() {
            dropZone.innerHTML = '<div>' + uploadFile.files[0].name + 
                                 '<button class="removeFile" onclick="fileRemove(event)">
                                 <i class="far fa-times"></i></button></div>'
            dropZone.classList.add('drop-success');
        };

function fileRemove() {
  dropZone.onclick=''  // setting the onclick of drop-zone to none
  dropZone.innerHTML = '<span class="drop-zone__title">Drop your file here</span>' +
                       '<span class="drop-zone__subtitle">Or select a file</span>'
 dropZone.classList.remove('drop-success');
 uploadFile.value = '';
 dropZone.onclick= selectFile() // setting back onclick of drop-zone for selecting files
        }
```

My fileRemove() function is not performing well. It removes the files, sets back the content of the div, but immediately reopens the file selector - I want to prevent this. 
I was trying with setting the onclick on and off, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is this function call, which is clicking the file upload input again

```
function selectFile() {
 if (uploadFile.files.length == 0) uploadFile.click()
}
```

Not sure why you need to click that input from javascript if the user can click it normally, just commenting that line will do the trick

```
function selectFile() {
 if (uploadFile.files.length == 0){
  //uploadFile.click()
 } 
}
```

Full fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/zgranda/3scvbjmq/13/

**EDIT:** Updated the fiddle with your new comment, now it checks if the `event.target` has the class `removeFile`. Check the updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/zgranda/3scvbjmq/41/

Comment: I forgot to mention that my <input> is hidden, that's why i have selectFile() function , so Clicking on the drag/drop zone should upload a file, not on the input. That's why this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the fiddle, please check it out